# Finding palindromic numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So, I'm doing Project Euler to solidify my Ruby skills. I'm on problem #4, which reads:

> A palindromic number reads the same
>   both ways. The largest palindrome made
>   from the product of two 2-digit
>   numbers is 9009 = 91 * 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from
>   the product of two 3-digit numbers.

First, I'm trying to verify my code using the information from the first paragraph. I've defined a palindrome function as so:

```
def palindrome?(blah)
  string = blah.to_s
  string.reverse == string
end
```

My code looks like:

```
array = (90..99).to_a
array = array.map{|u| array.map{|y| u*y}}
array = array.sort
array = array.select{|u| palindrome?(u)}
puts array
```

The program doesn't output anything. If I do the following:

```
array = (90..99).to_a
array = array.map{|u| array.map{|y| u*y}}
array = array.sort
#array = array.select{|u| palindrome?(u)}
puts array
```

I get a long series of unsorted four-digit numbers, so I guess it's ignoring the sort. Finally, if I simply do:

```
#array = (90..99).to_a
#array = array.map{|u| array.map{|y| u*y}}
#array = array.sort

array = [7447, 9009, 3551, 2419]
array = array.select{|u| palindrome?(u)}
puts array
```

I get 7447 and 9009, like I should. Why is this happening?

I'm using 1.8.6, because that's the only version available on this Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
 new_arr = array.inject([]) { |a,u| a += array.map { |y| u*y } }
```

instead of

```
  array = array.map{|u| array.map{|y| u*y}}
```

it returns a nested "[ [8100,..],[],[] ] " type of array. So thats the reason why your code doesn't work

Comment: ARGH, of course. When I decided on the dual mapping approach I used, I figured I'd just flatten the nested arrays afterward... and then I completely forgot. Sigh.

Anyway, changed line 3 to array = array.flatten.sort and it works great. Oh well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This line of yours

```
array = array.map{|u| array.map{|y| u*y}}
```

returns a nested array, you should unwrap.

Hints: (but I'm not going to tell you how)

1. You probably don't need sort on the intermediary value
2. You need to remove duplicates

Tips:
next time, run your code in the interactive interpreter, that way you'll see the result of each line of code.

Answer (score 1):

### [This looks more understandable:-](http://www.dahal.co/blog/2014/01/25/project-euler-problem-4-in-ruby.html)

```
#Steps
    # Define a method for palindrome
    # List out all 3-digit numbers
    # Multiply each numbers by each numbers
    # List out all palindrome numbers
    # Choose the largest (max) palindrome number

    def is_a_palindrome?(n)
        n == n.to_s.reverse.to_i
    end
    
    def problem_four
        palindrome = [ ]
        array = 111.upto(999)
        array.each do |x|
            array.each do |y|
                multiply = x * y
                if is_a_palindrome?(multiply)
                    palindrome << multiply
                end
            end 
        end
        palindrome.max
    end
    
    puts problem_four
    
    #$ ruby problem_four.rb
        #906609
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

I have made this solution, I hope this will help some newbie

```
to=999
from=100
palindromes=[]
for i in from..to do
    for j in 1..to do
        k=i*j
        palindromes << k if k.to_s==k.to_s.reverse
    end
end
palindromes.max  #this will return 906609
```